# Problem understanding the definition (Markov Chain)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am reading the ''Quasi-Stationary Distributions - Markov Chains, Diffusions, and Dynamical Systems - Pierre Collet, Jaime San Martín, Servet Martínez'', and at the beginning of Chapter $2$, the author writes the following paragraph:

[image]

where $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{X}$.

> **My question:** If $\mathbb{P}_x$ is a family of probabilities in $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, and $\Omega$ is the set of the right continues trajectories, how the second bullet makes sense? $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ and, as far as I know, $A \not\in\mathcal{F}.$

**N.B.:** I know the normal definition of Markov Chain, but, I need to understand the definition of this book so that I can make progress in reading him.

Comment: If I'm correct, its like this: $A \notin \mathcal{B} (\mathcal X) $, but rather $ A \in \mathcal F$, so $A$ is some event that can be generated by the collection of  projections on the  respective points in $\mathcal X$. What the second bullet then actually says that for this fixed $A$, the mapping $ \mathbb P_{(.)} : x \rightarrow \mathbb P_{x} (A) $ IS $ (\mathcal B(\mathcal X), \mathcal B([0,1])) $-measurable, (hence continuos). Does this help you?

Comment: Yes, I thought that $A\in \mathcal B(\mathcal X))$ for some reason... sorry about that, do you mind explaining me the first Bullet? What does he mean by $\mathbb P_x(Y_0 =x)$ ?

Comment: Like @Kavi Rama Murthy stated below, this is indeed a measurable event. This first bullet just assures that for every probability measure $\mathbb P_{x} $ in the family, the process $Y$ almost surely starts at $ x$ (w. r. t. $\mathbb P_{x} $)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x \in \mathcal X $, $P_x$ is a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$. For fixed $A \in \mathcal F$, $P_x(A)$ is a  well defined number. Define $f:\mathcal X \to \mathcal X$ by $f(x)=P_x(A)$. The second bullet says that this function is mesurable in the sense that for each $A \in \mathcal F$, $\{x:P_x(A) \in B)\} \in \mathcal B(\mathcal X)$ for every Borel set $B$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Another quick question, can you explain me the first bullet? What does he mean by $\mathbb{P}_x(Y_0 = x)$? How $Y_0^{-1}^(x)\in\Omega$ or $Y_0  =x \in \Omega$?

Comment: $Y_0$ is function from $\Omega$ into $\mathcal X$ and it is measurble so $\{Y_0=x\}$ is an event in $\Omega$.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. Because the author said that the process $\{Y_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ takes values in $\mathcal X$ and the trajectories belong to $\Omega$, what I understand from that is that the function $Y(\cdot,\omega) \in \Omega$, for each $\omega$ fixed. So... I am not sure why $Y_0:\Omega \to \mathcal{X}$, can you explain to me what I am confusing?

Comment: Each point of $\Omega$ is a function $\omega$ of the time variable $t$ with values in $\mathcal X$. $Y_t(\omega)$ is defined as $\omega (t)$. So each $Y_t$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathcal X$.

Comment: What you are saying makes A LOT of sense, but I have a final question. What does he mean by '' The process $(Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ takes ... and  $\textit{its trajectories belong to }\Omega$''? As far as I know, the definition of trajectory is the function $t\mapsto Y_t(\omega)$, for a fixed $\omega \in$  the Sample Space.

Comment: They are making special choice of the sample space here. A sample point $\omega$ is itself  a trajectory $Y_t(\omega)$, so $\Omega$ is space of functions on the time interval.

Comment: OOOOH I understand now... I am feeling a little dump now, thx for the Thanks for the help and patience.